# How do I bind a specific parameter to an instance of a custom annotation?

Tags: java, guice

How do I make the following work using Guice?

```
// The Guice Module configuration
void configure() {
  // The following won't compile because HelpTopicId is abstract.
  // What do I do instead?
  bind(new TypeLiteral<String>(){}).
      annotatedWith(new HelpTopicId("A")).toInstance("1");
  bind(new TypeLiteral<String>(){}).
      annotatedWith(new HelpTopicId("B")).toInstance("2");
}

public @interface HelpTopicId {
  public String helpTopicName();
}

public class Foo {
  public Foo(@HelpTopicId("A") String helpTopicId) {
    // I expect 1 and not 2 here because the actual parameter to @HelpTopicId is "A"
    assertEquals(1, helpTopicId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this would be to use `@Provides` methods:

```
@Provides @HelpTopicId("A")
protected String provideA() {
  return "1";
}
```

Alternatively, you could create an instantiable implementation of the `HelpTopicId` annotation/interface similar to the implementation of `Names.named` (see [NamedImpl](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/name/NamedImpl.java)). Be aware that there are some special rules for how things like `hashCode()` are implemented for an annotation... `NamedImpl` follows those rules.

Also, using `new TypeLiteral<String>(){}` is wasteful... `String.class` could be used in its place. Furthermore, for `String`, `int`, etc. you should typically use `bindConstant()` instead of `bind(String.class)`. It's simpler, requires that you provide a binding annotation, and is limited to primitives, `String`s, `Class` literals and `enum`s.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor `Foo(String)` has to be annotated with `@Inject`.

Instead of using your own `HelpTopicId` annotation, you should try with Guice `Named` annotation.

```
void configure() {
  bind(new TypeLiteral<String>(){}).annotatedWith(Names.named("A")).toInstance("1");
  bind(new TypeLiteral<String>(){}).annotatedWith(Names.named("B")).toInstance("2");
}

public class Foo {
  @Injected
  public Foo(@Named("A") String helpTopicId) {
    assertEquals("1", helpTopicId);
  }
}
```

If you want to roll out your own implementation of `@Named` interface, take a look at the Guice's implementation in the package [`com.google.inject.name`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/name/).

Comment: All valid points ... still, the code in `configure()` won't compile.

Comment: I've just tried and the `configure()` overwritten method is compiling fine. What's the message that the compiler is giving?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was too quick for my own good. I specifically asked about custom annotations, not named ones (I am familiar with those).