# Is 'value' a java keyword?

Tags: java, annotations

It seems to have a special meaning in annotations - it allows you to skip the parameter names when instaniating an annotation.

```
@Foo(bar = "abc") // a normal instantiation of an annotation
@Foo("abc") // if bar were renamed 'value'
```

Where is this documented? Is `value` a keyword or not? [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571680/how-do-i-bind-a-specific-parameter-to-an-instance-of-a-custom-annotation/6571718#6571718).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a regular keyword, as it's not listed in [section 3.9 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.9). In particular, you can use it as an identifier anywhere you like, as far as I'm aware.

The use of `value` by default for an annotation value is specified in [section 9.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.7):

> The third form of annotation, single-element annotation, is a shorthand designed for use with single-element annotation types:
>
> ```
> SingleElementAnnotation:
>    @ TypeName ( ElementValue )
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for the normal annotation:
>
> ```
>    @TypeName ( value = ElementValue )
> ```

Answer (score 7):

No, `value` is **not** a keyword in Java. If only one parameter is given to an annotation and that annotation only has one element that is called `value`, then the name `value` can be omitted when using the annotation. Annotations are explained here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html
And documented in [section 9.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html) in the JLS:

Answer (score 3):

`value` is the default field into which annotation data is placed. `value` however is not a java keyword (thanks for the reminder @gustafc).

[This is documented](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) where you would expect it to be - in the official documentation, which states:

> In annotations with a single element, the element should be named value

and

> It is permissible to omit the element name and equals sign (=) in a single-element annotation whose element name is value

Comment: True. Additional info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

Comment: However, if we want to be picky, `value` is not a keyword: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.9