# How to only autowire a specific class in JUnit spring test?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I want to write a kind of integration test, but only for a specific class.
Which means I want all fields in that class to be automatically wired, but neglect any classes inside the same directory.

Is that possible?

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class JunitTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
}

//how to only scan that specific class?
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyService.class, MyInjectedService.class})
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

}


@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyInjectedService service;
}
```

Here I want spring to neglect any classes in the same directories as the both `basePackageClasses` mentioned.

Comment: You can find this answer is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787722/spring-boot-field-injection-with-autowire-not-working-in-junit-test/59409695#59409695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of filters to customize scanning. There you can extend the ComponentScan Annotation with Attributes like this:

```
@ComponentScan(
basePackages = {"com.my.package"}, 
useDefaultFilters = false,
includeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {MyService.class, MyInjectedService.class})
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The `classes` attributes supported by `@ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` are only required to reference *annotated classes*; they do not have to be `@Configuration` classes.

So with that in mind, you should be able to completely forgo component scanning and simply declare your two annotated components as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class, MyInjectedService.class})
public class JUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    // ...
}
```

Having said that, if the above is your goal, it might not make any sense to use Spring Boot's testing support. In other words, if `MyService` and `MyInjectedService` do not rely on any features of Spring Boot, you can safely replace `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` with `@ContextConfiguration`.

Regards,

Sam (author of the *Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Except that you have here to provide the implementation in classes array, not the interface.

Comment: That's correct. In this example, `MyService` is the implementation. So that's fine. As for `MyInjectedService`, we cannot tell if it's an interface or the concrete implementation based on the example. So I just assumed both _types_ were concrete implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Import` annotation. It's more readable and shorter than using the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Import(value = {MyService.class, MyInjectedService.class})
public class JUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Simple and accurate! Thx!

Comment: you don't need to specify `value=`, you can just write `@Import({MyService.class, MyInjectedService.class})` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571827/is-value-a-java-keyword