# Spring boot field injection with autowire not working in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to inject DeMorgenArticleScraper in a test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DeMorgenArticleScraperTest {

    @Autowired
    private DeMorgenArticleScraper deMorgenArticleScraper;

    ...
}
```

The DeMorgenArticleScraper component has some configuration going on for itself, but the IDE/compiler is not complaining about them.

```
@Component
public class DeMorgenArticleScraper extends NewsPaperArticleScraper {

    @Autowired
    public DeMorgenArticleScraper(
            @Qualifier("deMorgenSelectorContainer") SelectorContainer selector,
            GenericArticleScraper genericArticleScraper,
            @Qualifier("deMorgenCompany") Company company) {
        super(selector, genericArticleScraper, company);
    }

    ...
}
```

The constructor parameters that are annotated with @Qualifier, are defined in a Config.class With @Bean. The class itself has @Configuration. I figure the problem is not situated here.

The IDE warns me already, no bean found...autowired members must be defined in a bean. But as far as I know, it is defined in a bean with the @Component annotation. All other bean wiring seems ok as the Spring boot application can start (when I comment out the test class).

Comment: Commenting by memory, should it be "@InjectMocks" that should go in DeMorgenArticleScraperTest instead of "@Autowired". I don't remember having "@Autowired" anotation in Junittest

Comment: I played around with the class annotation of the test after your comment and found something that works. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest that you answer your own question with the solution for Stack overflow sake! Glad it helped

Comment: I'll better answer first and comment second in the future :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@SpringBootTest` is fairly heavyweight, and for all intents and purpose will load your entire application, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications, it's fairly heavyweight and dramatically affects test time. Depending on what you are trying to test you may want to look into

- Slice tests e.g. `@JsonTest`, `@DataJpaTest`, `@WebMvcTest` etc. , https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests. Benefit of these tests are not only will they not load everything, thus faster, but will try to hunt out the relevant configurations.
- Plain old `@ContextConfiguration`and point to the relevant `@Configuration`'s required to load beans needed for the test https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#contextconfiguration

Comment: Ah now I found what I was looking for. I read about the ContextConfiguration annotation but I missed the fact that it is possible to pass Component annotated classes to it. Ty!

Comment: I agree with this answer, SpringBootTest is too much for what I wanted to test. I needed to Autowire a `@Configuration` class holding property values. In this case, for me, it worked using the `@ContextConfiguration`, plus the `@TestPropertySource("prop-file")` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties(Conf.class)`

Comment: Use slice tests and mock certain dependent but "not required for tests" beans with `@MockBean` annotation

Answer (score 10):

I replaced

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

with

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

This appears to be working fine: I see Spring boot firing up and loading beans. I'll keep this question open for a short while for better suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into similar problem where my spring context was not getting initialized and therefore I was not able to inject the bean with `@Autowired` annotation. Then I came across this post and tried with the below annotations as suggested by @progonkpa and it started working.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

But then I realized that `@SpringBootTest` already contains `@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})` annotation which is Junit5 equivalent of `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` thus it should load spring-context while running the test. Then I found out the silly mistake I made to import `@Test` annotation from junit4(i.e `org.junit.Test;`) instead of junit5(i.e `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`) library. I changed the `@Test` from junit5 library and it started working with a single annotation `@SpringBootTest`.

p.s : don't forget to exclude junit4 library from your dependency if you are using junit5

Comment: Depending on the version. I am running Spring Boot 1.5, and `@SpringBootTest` does not include `@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})` nor `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. So, it must be included alongside `@SpringBootTest`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

1. There is service, which I want to inject for testing but I want to test only `platformToSql(..)` method without launching whole Spring Boot application.

   ```java
   @Service
   public class ConverterToSqlImpl implements IConverterToSql {

       private final ISomeRepository someRepository;
       private final IUtilService utilService;

       public ConverterToSqlMainConstructorServiceImpl(
               IWorkerUtilService workerUtilService,
               ISomeRepository someRepository) {
           this.utilService = utilService;
           this.someRepository = someRepository;
       }

       @Override
       public String platformToSql(String platformName) {
           return "platform='" + platformName + "'";
       }

       @Override
       public String methodWhichUseRepositoryAndUtilBeans() {
           // some code which is not interested us
       }
   }
   ```
2. I create test class. It is necessary to mock beans because they are not need for test method.

   ```java
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest(classes = {ConverterToSqlImpl.class})
   //@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConverterToSqlImpl.class})
   @MockBeans({@MockBean(IUtilService.class), @MockBean(ISomeRepository.class)})
   public class SqlConverterConstructorTest {

       @Autowired
       private IConverterToSqlMainConstructorService convertToSql;

       @Test
       public void platformTest() {
           String platformSql = convertToSql.platformToSql("PLATFORM_1");
           String expectedSql = "platform='PLATFORM_1'";
           Assert.assertEquals(platformSql, expectedSql);
       }
   }
   ```

`@SpringBootTest(classess = {})` load to `ApplicationContext` only classess which are pointed out in `classess` section, **not** whole application with all beans will be lauched.

Also, as alternative to `@SpringBootTest` with `classes={..}`, you can uncomment line with `@ContextConfiguration`. It is plain old style.

Answer (score 0):

Using Junit5 worked for me and then just the `@SpringBootTest` and `@ActiveProfiles ("test")` annotation was sufficient. Of course, I had to have an `application-test.properties` in the `/test/resources` path.