# @WebMvcTest vs @ContextConfiguration when testing WebSocket controllers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, integration-testing, spring-websocket

I'm currently in the process of writing tests for my controllers in a Spring Boot project that uses WebSockets.
As information on the subject is hard to come by, my only lead is [this example](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/context) recommended by the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-testing).
Allow me to attempt to explain my forays so far, trying to understand and get my test environment set up. I'm following the context-based approach, and I'm torn between [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) and [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) (which the example uses).
My motivation behind using `@WebMvcTest` at all was this line from the Spring Boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.detecting-configuration):

> When testing Spring Boot applications, this [using `@ContextConfiguration(classes=…​)` in order to specify which Spring `@Configuration` to load, or using nested `@Configuration` classes within your test] is often not required. Spring Boot’s `@*Test` annotations search for your primary configuration automatically whenever you do not explicitly define one.

`@WebMvcTest` thus seems particularly suited to the task as it focuses only on the web layer by [limiting the set of scanned beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.spring-mvc-tests) to only those necessary (e.g. `@controller`) rather than spinning up a complete `ApplicationContext`.

The code example I'm following uses field injection to initialize channel interceptors to capture messages sent through them.

```
@Autowired private AbstractSubscribableChannel clientInboundChannel;
@Autowired private AbstractSubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel;
@Autowired private AbstractSubscribableChannel brokerChannel;
```

As far as I can tell, these fields are what makes the presence of the `TestConfig` class (see code block at the end for full class definition) in the example necessary, since without it, I get an error saying no beans qualify as autowire candidates. I believe these two fields in `TestConfig` are the key:

```java
@Autowired
private List<SubscribableChannel> channels;
@Autowired
private List<MessageHandler> handlers;
```

However, without `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [WebSocketConfig::class])` *(`WebSocketConfig` being my own WebSocket configuration file)*, these two fields are always `null` resulting in errors.
So far, this would mean that `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [WebSocketConfig::class])` in combination with the presence of `TestConfig` are needed.

The interesting thing is that without `@WebMvcTest`, `clientInboundChannel`, `clientOutboundChannel`, and `brokerChannel` are never actually initialized. So what this leaves me with is that I need both `@WebMvcTest` **and** `@ContextConfiguration`, which somehow seems odd.
And with the last update to the example repo being more than two years old, I can't shake the feeling that it may be somewhat outdated.

This is what my test class (Kotlin) currently looks like. I've omitted the `createRoom` test case for brevity:

```kotlin
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [RoomController::class])
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [WebSocketConfig::class, RoomControllerTests.TestConfig::class])
class RoomControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var clientInboundChannel: AbstractSubscribableChannel

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var clientOutboundChannel: AbstractSubscribableChannel

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var brokerChannel: AbstractSubscribableChannel

    private lateinit var clientOutboundChannelInterceptor: TestChannelInterceptor

    private lateinit var brokerChannelInterceptor: TestChannelInterceptor

    private lateinit var sessionId: String

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        brokerChannelInterceptor = TestChannelInterceptor()
        clientOutboundChannelInterceptor = TestChannelInterceptor()
        brokerChannel.addInterceptor(brokerChannelInterceptor)
        clientOutboundChannel.addInterceptor(clientOutboundChannelInterceptor)
    }

    @Test
    fun createRoom() {
        // test room creation
        // ...
    }

    @Configuration
    internal class TestConfig : ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent?> {
        @Autowired
        private val channels: List<SubscribableChannel>? = null

        @Autowired
        private val handlers: List<MessageHandler>? = null

        override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            for (handler in handlers!!) {
                if (handler is SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler) {
                    continue
                }
                for (channel in channels!!) {
                    channel.unsubscribe(handler)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789237/4348037) was my first clue towards starting to understand how `@WebMvcTest` and `@ContextConfiguration` are meant to be used.
It would appear the line that is really necessary is `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [WebSocketConfig::class])`, since without it, the necessary configuration (my own `WebSocketConfig`, in this case) can't be found.

While `@WebMvcTest` (and test slices in general) does [automatically search](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.detecting-configuration) for the primary configuration, the configuration defined by the main application class is the one that's found since that class is the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

What's more, test slices such as `@WebMvcTest` flat out [exclude](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.user-configuration-and-slicing) `@configuration` classes from scanning, meaning they won't be included in the application context loaded by the test slice.
Supporting this is the fact that the test works if `@WebMvcTest` is replaced with `@SpringBootTest` — even without `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [WebSocketConfig::class])` — meaning that `WebSocketConfig` was loaded.

To summarize, as I see it, there are 3 ways to include a non-primary configuration in  the application context so that it's [detected in integration tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.using-the-springbootapplication-annotation):

- Annotate the test class with `@SpringBootTest` (and optionally `@ContextConfiguration` to restrict the number of loaded beans to only those needed)
- Annotate the test class with a test slice (e.g. `@WebMvcTest`) in conjunction with `@ContextConfiguration`
- Annotate the test class with a test slice (e.g. `@WebMvcTest`) and define the configuration in the main class (i.e. the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`)

Answer (score 0):

`@ContextConfiguration` is to load and configure an ApplicationContext for **integration tests** as per [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html).

> @ContextConfiguration defines class-level metadata that is used to
> determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for
> integration tests.

For `@WebMvcTest`, to create any collaborators use `@MockBean` or `@Import` as per [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html).

> Typically @WebMvcTest is used in combination with @MockBean or @Import
> to create any collaborators required by your @Controller beans.